# does Azure AD B2C provide one endpoint like user-info-uri from OIDC for each sign-up-or-in policy?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any user-info-uri endpoint for Azure AD B2C policy ? From the implementation of Spring security `DefaultOAuth2UserService`, it requires the user-info-uri for standard `Oauth2Login` process.

If no, how can we obtain the user info from AD B2C policy ?

Reference code from spring security:

```
@Override
public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
    Assert.notNull(userRequest, "userRequest cannot be null");

    if (!StringUtils.hasText(userRequest.getClientRegistration().getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri())) {
        OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(
            MISSING_USER_INFO_URI_ERROR_CODE,
            "Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: " +
                userRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(),
            null
        );
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
    }
    ...
```

Comment: does this discussion help https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/244 ?

Comment: no, this is for Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Azure AD B2C does support the user info endpoint only through the [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

If you are using built-in [User-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview) policies, then you will have to set it up yourself and hardcode the library to look at your custom endpoint. All the endpoint needs to simply do is read the id token, validate it, and then return the claims inside in a JSON format.

There is a feature request for this, on Azure AD [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ba84d6ca-c825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789).